# How Do I Output Multiple Scraped Datasets to Their Own .CSV Files in Python?

Tags: python, csv, file-io

So my original plan was to have all the scraped data sets write to one .csv file with each dataset in its own column, but I've been convinced that's not the way to go. So what I'd like help doing is figuring out how to write each dataset (str1, str2, str 3 in the example below) to its own csv file (e.g., data1.csv, data2.csv, data3.csv).

```
str1 = "\n".join(data1)
str2 = "\n".join(data2)
str3 = "\n".join(matches)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_str = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
outfilename = 'data-{}.csv'.format(now_str)
outpath = 'data/'
outFile = open(outfilename, 'write')
outFile.write(str1)
outfile.write(str2)
outfile.write(str3)
outFile.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: python provides `csv` module for easy writing http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a different file for each data set.

```
outfilename1 = 'data1-{}.csv'.format(now_str)
out_file1 = open(outfilename1, 'w')

outfilename2 = 'data2-{}.csv'.format(now_str)
out_file2 = open(outfilename2, 'w')

out_file1.write(str1)
out_file2.write(str2)
```

#### UPDATE:

Since your str3 only contains matches between the first two data sets, you can conditionally write to file 3 like this.

```
if str3:
    outfilename3 = 'data3-{}.csv'.format(now_str)
    out_file3 = open(outfilename3, 'w')
    out_file3.write(str3)
```

Comment: That appeared to work like a charm. Is there any way to have a file not written if the dataset is empty? For example, my str3 in the above example only includes matches between the other datasets, but if there are no matches, can I tell it not to write an empty .csv file?

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how you can conditionally write to file3.